# socket.io `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` on custom domain connection -- works with Openshift url

Tags: ssl, socket.io, openshift

If I connect client-side with:

```
https://prod-myapp.rhcloud.com:8443
```

I get a working socket.io connection.

However, if I change to my custom domain:

```
https://www.myapp.me:8443
```

I get a `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` error.

My client-side connection code is as follows, with `host` being one of the above urls:

```
var socket = io.connect(host, { query: 'currentUser=' + currentUserId,
                                                      secure: true });
```

How do I get my custom domain working?

---

EDIT

OK, this is officially driving me crazy. I created a new SSL Cert using Openshift CSR as @developercorey suggested below.

When I go to my site through my custom domain - `https://www.myapp.me` - I get a green lock in Chrome and when I click it it says `www.myapp.me - Identity Verified`.

Here's what I see when I click on the padlock in Chrome and go to `certificate information`:

[image]

However, if I go to `https://www.myapp.me:8443/socket.io/` I get a:

```
   This is probably not the site you are looking for!
   You attempted to reach www.myapp.me, but instead you 
   actually reached a server identifying itself as *.rhcloud.com.
```

So my `SSL Cert` seems to be working but connecting with socket.io isn't working.

---

SECOND EDIT

So if I `openssl` my custom domain I get the certificate and then this:

```
    subject=/serialNumber=LnhzJHxcX0bIdlH2ITnDgaewey8ce5g3/C=US/ST=North Carolina/L=Raleigh/O=Red Hat Inc/OU=RHC Cloud Opoerations/CN=*.rhcloud.com
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2468 bytes and written 456 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: FB3AD94948150496CD7269AED4A426EE2C2F4604653D129BBC93702B89CEA52E
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 97EA9B89E9B2FA9342F83E5FF10A18008B8D462334822D2C83F203C44D90D13B37C9F91C503B45CB90684B5156796138

    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1408758948
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

The only thing I can see is - `No client certificate CA names sent` - is this the problem?

Comment: have you been able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you install a custom SSL Certificate for your domain? if not, then the app-domain.rhcloud.com ssl certificate is not valid for your custom domain (same as if you visit it in a web browser, you get a warning)

Comment: I had it working on Heroku with my custom domain and am now migrating to Openshift since Heroku doesn't handle websockets so well, so I assumed the SSL Cert on my own domain was still in valid as I just changed the CNAME on my DNS.

Comment: OK, so I needed to created a new SSL with a CSR from the new host, Openshift. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, still getting the same error from socket.io, `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`, after generating a new SSL Cert with a CSR from Openshift.

Comment: Is it self signed? if so you will still get that error probably since the chain of trust is not authentic.

Comment: No, it's signed by Openshift... See my above edit. The cert shows trusted when I open the custom domain itself. However, the problem is with the socket.io connection. That's what's getting denied as insecure.

Comment: OpenShift does not sign SSL certificates for customers.  You would need to generate a CSR and then get a certificate from a CA.  The only SSL we provide is for the app-domain.rhcloud.com shared certificate.  I don't think you have installed an SSL certificate for your custom domain, as evidenced by this in the above (CN=*.rhcloud.com)

Comment: I added a screenshot of the 'certificate information' when I click on the padlock in Chrome in the URL bar. As you can see I definitely have an SSL cert installed for my custom domain. It's working for the site itself, just not the socket.io connection.

Comment: OK, so here's the root problem: When I go to `https://www.lexly.me` then it's fine, the cert is there, the padlock is OK. When I go to `https://www.myapp.me:8443/` then I get the SSL error and Chrome says: `This is probably not the site you are looking for! You attempted to reach www.myapp.me but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.rhcloud.com`. So it's a problem with the port?

Comment: Sorry to comment on this old thread -- but did you find the solution? I mean, to the problem of getting this ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE when connecting to socket.io on a custom port?

Answer (score -2):

Your DNS is broken:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.myapp.me:8443 -debug
gethostbyname failure
connect:errno=0
```

In fact, I'm not getting a response from any DNS server (authoritative or non-authoritative):

```
$ dig www.myapp.me a

; <<>> DiG 9.8.5-P1 <<>> www.myapp.me a
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 45813
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.myapp.me.          IN  A

;; Query time: 3177 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.1.10#53(172.16.1.10)
;; WHEN: Fri Aug 22 21:10:47 EDT 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 30
```

Fix DNS and it should work. That's assuming your server has a valid certificate and its listening on port 8443.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the confusion. I used `myapp` instead of the real name.  However, I did just now try openssl and I pasted the results in an edit above.